# How to handle duplicate data or avoid clashes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

We are trying to build Resource booking system and user can make booking for location or people in the system. Multiple users may make the multiple bookings for same resource for same timing.

For example, 
user A, B and C are trying to book Location-A for the following timing.

User A 
=> 17/03/2015 10:00 to 12:00 
       => 17/03/2015 14:00 to 15:00
       => 18/03/2015 10:00 to 12:00
       => 18/03/2015 14:00 to 15:00

User B 
 =>  17/03/2015 11:00 to 12:00 
       => 18/03/2015 10:00 to 12:00

User C 
=> 17/03/2015 11:30 to 13:30

The system needs to handle resource clashes to avoid double booking for the same timing or overlap timing. Only one of the user can take the resource and the rest booking must be failed. My question is what is the proper way to handle it? Should we use transaction or table lock before we insert the data into table? We are using Visual studio 2008 and SQL server 2008. Thank you so much for your advise and we really appreciate it.

Comment: Unless otherwise coded, last in wins.  You could use something like a timestamp - if you update the record and the timestamp of the object you're using to update and the timestamp of the record being updated don't match, then something changed between the time of the last read and the current update.  LINQ to SQL was capable of doing something like that - EF may be as well.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your comments. I am also thinking in that way. There will be 'last updated datetime' for each resource in server side and it needs to keep in client site when they access the resource. The system needs to compare it before make any changes. What we worry is the user may get same value if they access the resource in same time.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 business processes involved here.

- Process one:

**Show available seats.**

- Process two:

**Book a Location.**

Since these processes don't follow one another immoderately, and since 2 people may select the same Location-A the concurrency issue arises.

If your database design assigns the correct uniqueness constraint so that the combination of:

-LocationID

-TimeStamp (E.g 10 To 12 ,15 to 17)

are unique, then the database will prevent duplicates.

The following scenario is also possible but will be taken care of by the above suggested implementation:

Assuming a grid view of available for a given theater and a given event can be displayed:

1. User1 displays available Resource  (and gets=> 17/03/2015 10:00 to 12:00 Location A)
2. User2 displays available seats (and gets => 17/03/2015 10:00 to 12:00 Location A)
3. User1 talks a bit with the on the phone
4. User2 goes and books (17/03/2015 10:00 Location A)
5. User1 tries to book (17/03/2015 10:00 Location A) (because it shows as available on his screen)
6. The unique index prevents step 5 from commuting the data.

So all what you need to do may be nothing more correct database design and proper choice on constraints.

Other more complex approaches are possible if you want, using transaction queues. In this case, requests are written first to a queue then fires a process every n seconds but that is hardly necessary or practical in your case.

The really interesting part is what should the list grid for user 1 show?

Comment: Hi Dabhi, thanks for your answer. We don't want to hold the slots for the users. It is something like first in first out. The one who make the first booking may win the slot. That is why multiple users may book for the same slots in same time. We need to do concurrent checking in backend. Again, thanks for your answer. It gives us some idea. (Y)